# how did this algebraic expression get reduced to this?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x^{1/2}}{x} + \frac{\ln{x}}{2x^{1/2}} = \frac{2+\ln{x}}{2x^{1/2}}$$

I tried multiplying both sides by least common denominator and reducing but it didn't work.. I've spent a long time on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do things with maximal crudeness. We won't even look for a least common denominator. We will just multiply top and bottom of the first by $2x^{1/2}$, top and bottom of the second by $x$ to get the **same** denominator. We end up with
$$\frac{2x+x\ln x}{(2x^{1/2})(x)}.$$
Now if we wish to simplify we can cancel an $x$ from top and bottom. We get
$$\frac{2+\ln x}{2x^{1/2}}.$$

Comment: thats what i thought I did but for some reason I didnt see the x in both sides to cancel out. thats much easier, thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{x^{1/2}}{x}=\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}$$

Comment: @JL Hint 2: Multiply by $\frac{x^{-1/2}}{x^{-1/2}}$.

Comment: $x=x^1=x^{2/2}$, now use exponent rules. Namely that $\frac{a^b}{a^c}=a^{b-c}$. So $x^{1/2}/x^{2/2}=x^{1/2-2/2}=x^{-1/2}=1/x^{1/2}$.

Comment: @JL: Of course we have $x\neq 0$ and certainly Atarixia considered this point here.

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side = $\frac{2}{2x^{1/2}} + \frac{\ln x}{2x^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{x^{1/2}} + \frac{\ln x}{2x^{1/2}} =  \frac{x^{1/2}}{x} + \frac{\ln x}{2x^{1/2}}$